# Parse Java OffsetDateTime to JS Date

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, java-time

In my JS bases microservice, I am somehow getting the following following JSON from my java microservice which internally uses OffSetDateTime.

```
{
   "eventTime":   "eventTime":{
      "offset":{
         "totalSeconds":0,
         "id":"Z",
         "rules":{
            "fixedOffset":true,
            "transitions":[

            ],
            "transitionRules":[

            ]
         }
      },
      "year":2018,
      "month":"NOVEMBER",
      "dayOfMonth":9,
      "dayOfWeek":"FRIDAY",
      "dayOfYear":313,
      "monthValue":11,
      "hour":5,
      "minute":57,
      "second":21,
      "nano":716000000
   }
}
```

instead of just

```
{"eventTime" :"2018-11-09T05:57:21.716Z" }
```

How do I parse this in JS? The following gives me NaN

```
Date.parse(eventTime)
```

Where eventTime is the first string mentioned above.

Comment: You should fix your Java service so it delivers just `{"eventTime" :"2018-11-09T05:57:21.716Z" }`.

Comment: As Ole V.V. suggests, you should fix your Java backend to send a `String` in your desired [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format: `myOffsetDateTime.toInstant().toString()`

Comment: Yes, that is what eventually needs to be done but I am curious if there is any JS library which accepts this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it manually. Something like this will work:

```js
var res = {
   "eventTime":{
      "offset":{
         "totalSeconds":0,
         "id":"Z",
         "rules":{
            "fixedOffset":true,
            "transitions":[

            ],
            "transitionRules":[

            ]
         }
      },
      "year":2018,
      "month":"NOVEMBER",
      "dayOfMonth":9,
      "dayOfWeek":"FRIDAY",
      "dayOfYear":313,
      "monthValue":11,
      "hour":5,
      "minute":57,
      "second":21,
      "nano":716000000
   }
};
var d = new Date(
  res.eventTime.year, 
  res.eventTime.monthValue - 1, 
  res.eventTime.dayOfMonth, 
  res.eventTime.hour, 
  res.eventTime.minute, 
  res.eventTime.second,
  res.eventTime.nano/1000000
);

alert(d.getTime());
```

Javascript does not support nanoseconds. It only supports granularity upto milliseconds.

Also, months are from `0 - 11` so, you need to do `value - 1` for the month value in your case.